# Google webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I am using google webmaster tool , and i have a problem.
I have succeeded to submit links to google that will be show on google when searching them, but now when i submit a new pages, i don't see it on google search. 
For example i want to submit the following links to google but can`t: 
"http://www.aaa.com/test?abc=123"
or "http://www.aaa.com/test.html".

Thanks.

Comment: Allow a few days and then search Google for `site:mysite.com` to see all indexed pages. You add pages to Google index, not to search results.

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamical Sitemap for your site and submit it to Google Search Console: https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google crawls web pages that are submitted to it through sitemap.xml file. When you add new page to your website, you need to do the following steps:

1. Update the pages in your sitemap.xml file hosted on your server.
2. Resubmit this sitemap file in google webmaster tool/search console.
3. Use option Crawl as google to make the google bot re-index your site. This can also be done automatically as google occasionally visits submitted websites based on its algorithm.
   For detailed explanation on how to add website to google and submit sitemap files, you can visit "[How to add website on Google Webmaster or Search console](http://webolute.com/blog/website/how-to-add-website-on-google-webmaster)"